# Ubuntu 20.04, Kaffeine stop working on TV but w_scan is ok

Tags: 20.04, accessibility, dvb-t

Nearly at the same time kaffeine TV stopped working on ubuntu 20.04 and raspbian. w_scan works on both, different TV transponders were used.

Message in swedish is:

> Hittade inte en enhet med giltiga inställningar, eller är åtkomsträttigheter felaktiga

translated

> Did not find a device with valid settings, or access rights are incorrect

What may be the problem?

Problem solved: Needed a source for DVB-T2 in settings...